# ¿cómo inhabilitar y deshabilitar un select con otro select?

Tags: javascript

## este es el select principal:

id=tipo_boleto

```
<select id="tipo_boleto" name="tipo_boleto" >
```

#### y los otros select son

### id=boleto_2d

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="8" id="boleto_2d" size="5" name="boletos[2D][cantidad]" placeholder="0" disabled>
```

### id=boleto_3d

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="8" id="boleto_vip" size="5" name="boletos[VIP][cantidad]" placeholder="0" disabled>
```

### id=boleto_vip

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="8" id="boleto_3d" size="5" name="boletos[3D[cantidad]" placeholder="0" disabled>
```

el codigo que tendo para habilitarlo es:

```
$('#tipo_boleto').change(function(){
  $('#boleto_2d').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#tipo_boleto').change(function(){
  $('#boleto_3d').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#tipo_boleto').change(function(){
  $('#boleto_vip').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

pero el problema es que al cualquier cambio en el select principal se habilitan los tres y quiero que al seleccionar en el principal : "2D" me habilite el 2d y al volver a poner el principal en value 0 se vuelva a desabilitar el segundo select

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás analizando el valor del *select*. Necesitas una sola función donde primero deshabilitas todos los campos y luego analizas el valor seleccionado para saber cuál habilitar:

```js
$('#tipo_boleto').change(function(){
  // Deshabilitar todos
  $('#boleto_2d').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#boleto_3d').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#boleto_vip').attr('disabled', true);
  // Habilitar solo uno, dependiendo del valor
  switch ($(this).val()) {
      case '2D':
          $('#boleto_2d').removeAttr('disabled');
          break;
      case '3D':
          $('#boleto_3d').removeAttr('disabled');
          break;
      case 'VIP':
          $('#boleto_vip').removeAttr('disabled');
          break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tipo_boleto" name="tipo_boleto">
  <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
  <option value="2D">2D</option>
  <option value="3D">3D</option>
  <option value="VIP">VIP</option>
</select>


<input type="number" min="0" max="8" id="boleto_2d" size="5" name="boletos[2D][cantidad]" placeholder="2D" disabled>

<input type="number" min="0" max="8" id="boleto_vip" size="5" name="boletos[VIP][cantidad]" placeholder="VIP" disabled>

<input type="number" min="0" max="8" id="boleto_3d" size="5" name="boletos[3D][cantidad]" placeholder="3D" disabled>
```